# Error using Facebook Log in with PHP sdk 4.0

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to code Facebook log with php sdk 4.0 in to my website I have setup all the settings on my facebook app and im sure all the details are correct in my files.  so my users can log in using they're Facebook account but I have run into a problem. I go to my website and click the log in link and it goes back to my website but this time it has a ?code= with lots of params and a error is displayed

And just to say the domain is a local domain I edited my hosts file and added

```
127.0.0.1 ashleyisawsome.com
```

And the error i have when i click login is

```
Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb\Facebook\FacebookRequest.php on line 154
```

I looked in FacebookRequest.php and all i found was the line below

```
return static::$httpClientHandler ?: static::$httpClientHandler = new FacebookCurlHttpClient();
```

So i am guessing the error is with the

```
new FacebookCurlHttpClient();
```

Can anyone help me out with this please? Here is my main index.php file

```
<?php

 session_start();
 include 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php';
 include 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php';
 require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
 require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
 require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
 require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
 require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
 require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
 require_once( 'Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
 Use Facebook\FacebookSession;
 Use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
 use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
 use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
 use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
 use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
 use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
 use Facebook\GraphObject;
 use Facebook\GraphUser;
 FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('',     '');
 $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://ashleyisawsome.com/fb/index.php');
 $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
 if($session != NULL){
 echo "Logged In !<br>"; 
 $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
 $response = $request->execute();
 $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
 echo $graph->getName();
 }
 else{
 echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login</a>';
 }
 ?>
```

EDIT : I have fixed this but it know says this?

```
Fatal error: Interface 'Facebook\FacebookHttpable' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb\Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient.php on line 31
```

Comment: You have to require Facebook/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php also. But I would suggest to setup an autoloader so you don't have to include every single file

Comment: And how can i do that?

Comment: Just like you do `require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );` you have to require the other file too

Comment: I have done that. But will i have to include every file? Im usure what a autoloader is.

Comment: Search stackoverflow or google for php class autoloader

Comment: I have required that file you said but now i have this error? Fatal error: Interface 'Facebook\FacebookHttpable' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb\Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient.php on line 31

Comment: Because you need to require Facebook/FacebookHttpable.php also

Comment: Does it have to be _once? or just require

Comment: it should be require_once

Comment: I have done all you said and require_once them two files in index.php and now im stil getting that error?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Fatal error: Interface 'Facebook\FacebookHttpable' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb\Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient.php on line 31 Like before nothing changed

Comment: Make sure that you require Facebook\FacebookHttpable before Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient

Comment: And now i get this error. The other one is fixed Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\FacebookCurl' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\fb\Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient.php on line 83

Comment: Make one guess what you need to do

Comment: Lets try it and see if it works.

Comment: I have fixed it, Thankyou for your help, I just had to include the curl file!

Comment: Is there any way i can fix this? Exception occured, code: 200 with message: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Comment: Make sure to ask for the right permissions before trying to do it

Comment: How can i do that? I can't find any docs about it on facebook. And it doesnt even popup when logging in to allow anything? And when i reload the page it logs out? (Goes back to the "Login" link page)

Answer (score 1):

You must include / call the FacebookHttpable class / namespace -BEFORE- the FacebookCurlHttpClient class / namespace

```
//all other requires here
require_once( 'FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );

//all other namespaces here
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
```